# How to have PHP display data from a program that runs asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, php, python-2.7, mamp

## Question

I have a backend server program that is currently called through PHP with `echo exec("python programFilePath $variables");` This method worked well, but then I added a new component to the python program. This new component makes a web request and then the necessary data is printed on the terminal output screen.

Unfortunately, the `php echo exec` function won't print this data, ostensibly because python's beautiful soup module runs requests asynchronously. Obviously, this breaks the webpage if a key dynamic component doesn't work.

*How to make php run the program but also allow it to display the data?*

## Edits

[Here is the code for the problematic python script I am trying to run.](http://pastebin.com/Bh22aQw0)

It works perfectly when run through IDLE or terminal. But, when I run it with the php command:

```
echo exec ("python /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Exeter_Bookstore_Project/lab/Python/amazonParser.py");
```

it is the only test that doesn't work on my debug page:
[image]

*Does anyone have an idea why that is?*

Comment: What you are saying contradicts the documentation of `exec`, which tells us that PHP waits for the process to terminate, *unless* you redirect the program's output to somewhere else.

Comment: @PietervandenHam I haven't redirected the program's output, but I've just updated with more info on methods I used to debug and also gave a link to the script I am using. Are there any obvious issues with the script itself?

Answer (score 0):

`exec` is synchronous, meaning it will wait for the process to terminate before moving the PHP script forward.

Likewise, `echo` will wait for the `exec` process to complete before outputting the results.

So if you're experiencing some short-circuit problems, the solution is likely with your Python script.

> This method worked well, but then I added a new component to the
>   python program. This new component makes the script take 2-3 seconds
>   to run...

Maybe the component you added is running asynchronously? If so, the Python script could be returning execution to PHP immediately, then running your new component on a different thread. So from PHP's perspective, it looks like Python is finished.

Comment: Ok, so how can I force the script to run synchronously? I've given a link to the script in an edit, would really appreciate it if you could look over it and give me some pointers. I'm a bit of a noob in this area.

Comment: i suggest you consider using multiprocessing module available in python since 2.6

use a callback for your asynchronous calls in your python script.

and in your callbacks write the remaining script...

so a level of synchronization is achieved for the same...

1. maybe say like call the pool and create a new job of your new documented lines of code
2. have a follow up with the callback which should be called once your code finishes execution
3. in the callback have the remaining script as normal